# Iterating through/finding a match in two JSON object arrays

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

I have two JSON objects that are read from files:

```
var fulljson = require('./full.json');
var partialjson = require('./partial.json');
```

The files look as below:

full.json

```
[
{"timestamp": 4370.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [2916119854,2916101166,2949851150,3218221070,3200458015,3196130605,3196065789,3196072588,3196072604,2663388076,2663657892,2663461028,2663452836,2387804404,3457552404,3459657989,3447087375,3434606350,3434588942,3433995022,3434056478,3429402926,3443035502,2637796574,2635706446,2635698254,2618933535,2618979631,2618965807,2618957359,2639988263,2681746022,2593661926,2593678327,2610487735,2610491813,2614658212,2574814388,2302475460,2302533060,2302559557,2635993351,2635997446,2640192278,2644404022,2644475686,2677866039,2677861957,2682103749,2505934796,2505934300,2504820124,3578641852,3574316460,3574173092,3574320548,4112242100,4112380336,4099273168]},
{"timestamp": 4380.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [2228797364,2228787844,2220399236,2269027020,2252259020,2250946380,2523571532,2523440220,2519262316,2536273004,2503869805,2508066795,2516467450,2512269018,2243702494,2277256926,2415662590,2415658362,2382168122,2382172186,2381067290,2380805146,2355641371,2355715337,2356927773,2289692124,2295984092,2312744636,2329519788,2321057708,2316862396,2316927452,3390746653,3390742541,3395005461,3487214613,3453659156,3705325652,3696938164,2618934452,2619262388,2625558148,2625029765,3707131541,3707008741,3698353893,3698353775,3696239999,2622762110,2639539326,2681681982,2656443710,2664844574,2664843038,2661151518,2392646414,2258412319,2275185275,2279391977]},
{"timestamp": 4390.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [2356725484,2356791176,2357123016,2625568760,2641801192,2671161320,2654912456,2652870089,2673653193,3217859819,4291601643,3041715370,3037484202,3038578058,2501773210,2505967278,2648584878,2643731183,2643731039,2643730959,2643723039,2224292127,2229022991,2228053023,2228087935,2228074750,2236582303,2270136717,2269822349,3595215244,3591287180,4144989132,4144857964,4111828780,4049444140,3781004348,3781073965,3776898093,3844038783,3827245279,3829282031,3829270503,3833466599,3841920755,4108140033,4103876096,4120673792,4137174800,1452962560,1459233344,1459229376,1458438785,1458505379,1450979234,1450978722,1432104354,1415343254,1423352966,1425450438]},
{"timestamp": 4400.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [4237029062,4237881030,4242058709,4244225236,4244241620,4248336596,4246497524,2098858164,2100965300,2100969173,2104104643,1575617218,1470628594,1470632802,1454907682,1454908466,1454961923,1203414273,1207609088,1174054656,1174045184,1157333584,1148756576,1148773348,3296321892,3563641964,3588802797,2515060975,2515253434,2550049194,2541595562,2549921418,3067916938,3063526346,3065754090,4143509614,3056136302,3072868590,3039502815,3022940111,3157192269,3161381468,2902366748,2897525276,2914298380,2813635084,3069556492,3061826316,3060613501,3056337391,3056349358,3190558886,3211657382,3724411378,3703443778,3703509250,3703317762,3439076610,3439144258]},
{"timestamp": 4410.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [4080961089,3795436002,3861430434,3865592994,3873983650,3874117810,3890903250,3890899139,1667917891,1630430273,1680810049,1680286017,1680290789,1679885039,1692402414,1689269994,1687437034,1703160538,3850660554,3884772042,4153314891,3884617288,3986404872,3992495896,3178800440,3107497256,3107579176,3107853608,3141403951,3139310446,3126723438,3130983270,3132621158,2595750374,2595750374,2662884546,2398676163,3459894465,3324693697,3609888192,3559557056,3564025792,1420739524,1420149701,1952760261,1949614461,1947488621,1947476841,1946428969,1833201193,1842301563,1842334331,1838136154,1838983498,4022115786,4277962187,4278039001,4198490328,4198457848]},
{"timestamp": 4420.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [76688145,76688131,213003011,263322371,112299778,116493778,1190235538,1190234513,1190370192,3329464976,3323173504,3323080336,3323145904,2261987040,2257660896,2257594848,2257594593,2274367715,2240858194,2245036114,2236652818,2500898066,2500896114,2500898674,2534522322,2533530051,2533546881,2534554496,2534542208,2501053408,2509253408,2442148128,2442135841,2175805731,2174757122,2174756866,2170554386,2167490610,3239135442,3238119810,3275868546,3284568450,1137084802,3343031682,3338843522,3338835330,3338711458,1460707810,1460707618,1462804786,1446224130,1445176582,1982070038,1998747942,1966496038,4113959214,4099803646,1423837582,1419513222]},
{"timestamp": 4430.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [1892691682,1888562146,1907571011,1404188738,330442818,49379522,36748530,34907299,38043811,63275171,1137086625,1137090785,1094885569,1091740737,1091736833,1165135617,3589516833,3619007011,3618941475,3602164259,3606363955,3610558227,3577714451,4097741585,4096692993,4100883219,4100968723,4117549155,4146918499,4130305267,3056469187,3056489617,3060752309,3064848100,3064782572,3081558620,3081559629,3081563727,3078416111,3057402862,3057451498,3057455534,3057586350,3061715118,3187545262,4244583582,4244071631,3707135439,3707168013,3707163917,3707097373,3707035948,3723780396,3748946220,3715593516,3716039981,3716040541,3724166991,3590014927]},
{"timestamp": 4440.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [3346321725,3308646685,3309298957,3559828749,1412349199,1416530973,1417579605,1434358853,1465749581,1448456269,1446481949,1446498351,1983370279,4129776743,4146490726,4100333286,4108783286,4108652182,4108650134,4104475270,4104348550,3584254402,3622916466,3622883623,3622887717,4159759652,4117819188,3562142484,3562273540,3562176324,3562428356,3579267029,3579786231,3581744127,3590132719,3590140399,3590157823,3590289229,3590223629,3589273421,3589273183,3590125341,3590125357,3590116141,3623665961,4135575865,4135579913,4064219400,4064218379,3527297083,4064278890,4085115370,4051500970,4033627018,4042052234,4037849818,4038046699,4037976552,2969480680]},
{"timestamp": 4450.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [3358367404,3425025708,3424827084,3424823116,3424823116,3425742396,3708857900,3746605612,3728784957,3737362013,3738351183,3738600399,3749102046,2642395630,2619195878,2619176038,2623499302,2625596470,2633853974,2633786390,2684166166,2665361686,2594062598,2610872847,2612904493,2579022444,2566446700,2557004520,2552810200,2604530376,2587815880,2587764617,2587763595,3665761690,3680242858,3679722666,3654760683,3688246377,3671483404,3687968772,1498460420,1493217600,1476436960,1543562144,1543567265,1548115891,1573281667,1602641283,3751693698,3468447138,3471371554,3731680546,3731684662,3727486774,3614238486,3588616966,3299263238,3299263303,3433513893]},
{"timestamp": 4460.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [1390381385,1457438665,3604657867,3604583114,3598287614,2524631790,2541413358,3178947054,3170608638,3170409566,3170469983,3170539717,3170547908,3094935668,3090709604,3090952300,3090952557,2822644589,2826838637,3909031525,3904114277,3902024277,3902025217,4169148161,2042635009,2067800903,1514353478,1514295758,1514328302,1514394862,1522551022,1539340494,1505781966,214104270,214367437,1288099020,1146536324,1146536324,1092014980,1092076180,1125630644,1129838260,1113024149,1112893079,1123382998,1123358694,1122243950,1122767214,1085022575,1085023543,1089369366,1082017046,1077726262,1077738598,1077734870,1127128518,1387175559,1387173509,1388283524]},
{"timestamp": 4470.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [3329212017,3337476723,3333282547,3333283554,3333224358,2259464358,2527899815,2523693231,2519172287,2535890063,2502339973,2486611845,3564611511,3522486759,3545522413,2454986989,2454986989,2992058861,2994604013,4068411117,4085188319,3523098254,3517853582,3500813710,1357454526,1366821034,1396181162,1379417515,1378444761,1399579609,1407972120,1407758600,1374204172,1349100548,1345039380,1345038644,1345173796,1345313056,1348918545,1357038914,1374831042,1397899666,1393639859,1393582499,3511706081,3520128481,3516066929,3516324864,3551972613,3551380743,3551061543,3555254886,3555223270,3546810030,3510568638,3493791390,3493802911,1367286159,1904091339]},
{"timestamp": 4480.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [4076389551,4079502575,4079498493,4046136399,1898586383,1898592015,1349387838,1349324646,1357656038,1353461746,280244099,1419073409,1417725312,1434551248,1455601600,1456645824,1450419920,1450222304,1446027936,3608212131,3612627622,3586470638,3621069422,2533195562,2523691050,2523453498,3068696602,3064576011,4138383368,4138376968,4276781576,4264198668,4264198940,4264423532,4265369701,4265353447,4265345186,2099130498,2086543490,2094925446,2090667670,1555905174,1556052630,1555823302,1559886535,1576583109,1610132964,1582869860,1448650212,1444524500,1444606404,1446704068,1983562228,4147888613,4117613925,3840780583,3840911661,3840908060,2767030796]},
{"timestamp": 4490.00, "duration": 10.00, "fingerprint": [2658886981,2675598789,2650457559,2633745894,2633616870,2633628790,2625174838,2498346263,2515250967,2533096983,2533218103,2658989862,2654757158,2654941234,3745447970,3558670370,3562930466,3571331395,3566084929,1419711184,1423725520,3562590656,1429994944,1462413696,1462409856,1450085045,1458539173,1986828981,1982109573,1982128533,4129677485,4146589805,4150775845,4150673701,4159578405,4159578629,1911435781,1894580791,1895565030,1895308974,1884830654,1884895678,1910192302,1925135519,851390607,854409357,854376521,845971753,845985577,862760491,871148075,594524698,590330378,841793290,1915536666,1932312618,1903083626,1911472362,1889460462]}
]
```

partial.json

```
[
{"timestamp": 0.00, "duration": 5.00, "fingerprint": [2228797364,2220399236,2220464772,2269035212,2252258892,2250946380,2523637068,2523456636,2519262316,2536264812,2503871849,2508066794,2516467450,2512334558,2243702494,2415667198,2415662586,2382102650,2382168090]},
{"timestamp": 5.00, "duration": 5.00, "fingerprint": [2619266964,2625554053,3707131525,3707066037,3698357989,3698353893,3696239983,2622499966,2639539326,2647992446,2681609534,2664828190,2664842526,2661143326,2661081870,2258412302,2258417211,2279375465,2271003369]},
{"timestamp": 10.00, "duration": 5.00, "fingerprint": [2356725500,2356795272,2357133256,2625552360,2641801192,2671161336,2654904264,2652739021,2673649097,4291601643,3217859818,3037521066,3037463738,3038709130,2501772958,2505967278,2648584878,2643731183,2643730975]}
]
```

So basically what I would like to achieve is to go over full.json file and specifically look through **fingerprint** array on every line for a match in partial.json fingerprint array and once there is a match, a timestamp would be printed/saved.

For example here partialjson[0].fingerprint[0] matches fulljson[1].fingerprint[0] so fulljson[1].timestamp would be printed etc. (doesn't matter if same timestamp gets printed multiple times as fingerprints could match on same timestamp).

Comment: Have you tried a particular algorithm? Are there any specific issues with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to parse the partial array and check against each object in the full array.

```
let timestamps = [];

// parse all partial items
partial.map( (item) => {

   // parse all fingerprints of each item
   item.fingerprint.map( (fprint) => {

      // parse all full items
      full.map( (fullitem) => {

         // check if the current fingerprint exists in the array of the current full item
         if (fullitem.fingerprint.indexOf(fprint) !== -1) {
            timestamps.push(fullitem.timestamp);
         }
      });
   });
});

console.log(timestamps);
```

For your dataset, the `timestamps` array will contain:

```
[4380, 4380, 4380, 4380, 4380, 4380, 4380, 4380, 4390, 4390, 4390, 4390, 4390]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!